# How to receive the SMS via twilio

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, twilio, visualforce

I have [installed the twilio package](https://www.twilio.com/docs/salesforce/install) and following components. How do I configure the two components? When customer sends an sms it does not create a case in the sandbox. I am unable to receive sms details. What is the twilio message url where should I give in the salesforce?

[image]

I am completely new to twilio configuration. Can someone please help.
Whenever customer sends an sms, then it should create a case in the sandbox automatically by using twilio api .

**Component 1: Visual force Fage**

```
<apex:page controller="TwilioRequestControllerContacts" action="{!init}" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <center>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Twilio Request Listener"></apex:pageBlock>          
    </center>
</apex:page>
```

**Component 2: Controller**

```
public with sharing class TwilioRequestControllerContacts 
{
    public String fromNumber      = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('From');
    public String toNumber        = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('To');
    public String body            = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Body');
    public PageReference init()
    {
    try
    {           
       System.debug('STEP 0 FROM: ==========>' + fromNumber);
       System.debug('STEP 1 TO: ===============>' + toNumber);
       System.debug('STEP 2 BODY: ==========>' + body);
       System.debug('STEP 3  ==============>');                 
       String account = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';   
       String token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
       TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(account,token);
       system.debug('STEP 4 test==3>'+client);
       if(fromNumber != null && toNumber != null) {  
       //my own logic                
        Case ca = new Case(Subject = fromNumber,Description = body,Origin = 'Phone');
           INSERT ca;       
           RETURN null;
       }
    }                
   catch(exception e){
        system.debug('STEP 7 error ==========>'+e);
   }
    RETURN null;
   }  
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to Receive the SMS via twilio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339900/unable-to-receive-the-sms-via-twilio)

Answer (score -1):

Go for this post, this will surely help you

http://abhithetechknight.blogspot.in/2014/06/salesforce-integration-with-twilio.html

Regards,
Abhi Tripathi
SFDC Certified Developer

Comment: Please include the basic points in your answer and have the link as a reference. That way, it the link is broken in the future, your answer can still stand on its own.

Comment: @user2352 It is send an sms.I need to receive the sms in salesforce by using twilio api.

Comment: I agree to @user2352 ,I am also sent an sms by using twilio api but unable to receive the sms

Comment: I have found the solution.Now I have receive the SMS via twilio API in Salesforce.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339900/unable-to-receive-the-sms-via-twilio