# How to get a Twilio SMS request in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, twilio, visualforce, apex

Right now I am sending the SMS via Twilio account. But Unable to receive SMS in Salesforce. How to get the Twilio SMS request in the Salesforce?

[image]

I have Twilio SMS URL; it hit the automatically open the my visual force page then controller send an SMS but it didn't receive the SMS details. My question is similar how to get SMS details [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326577/how-to-receive-the-sms-via-twilio). I have follow  [this document](http://clintlee.sys-con.com/node/1712284/mobile).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to receive the SMS via twilio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326577/how-to-receive-the-sms-via-twilio)

Comment: I have found the solution.Now I have receive the SMS via twilio API in Salesforce.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339900/unable-to-receive-the-sms-via-twilio